# Bond Duration hedging with long convexity

Tags: fixed-income, hedging, duration, convexity

How do you build a duration-neutral bond portfolio which is long convexity? can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

I would say you can go

- Long a bond with a low coupon
- Short a bond with a higher coupon

For instance current for US Treasury circa 10Y

- 2% 15NOV26, BPV 8.7265, Convx 89.9624
- 1.5% 15AUG26, BPV 8.3071, Convx 87.9649

Buy 1,000,000 of the 1.5% and Sell 951,939 of the 2% would give you positive convexity and 0 duration. Of course more extreme coupon differential will give you a much better convexity exposure.

Comment: your example "long 1,000,000 @ 2% and short 1,006,056 @ 1.5% contradicts your statement "Long a bond with a low coupon and Short a bond with a higher coupon"

Comment: I had used modified duration instead of BPV when I skipped the spot consideration, that's why it didn't work, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

More typically this refers to a portfolio like:

Long 100MM 10yr bond with coupon 3%
Short 180MM 5yr bond with coupon 3%

with the principal amounts chosen such that the BPVs in dollars are equal.   This portfolio is long convexity.

The term "duration neutral" does not imply matched maturity.